# Can I use a SMPS for powering pi and sensors connected to it

Tags: power-supply, sensor

BME280, BMA180 and BMP180 are the sensors that I am going to connect with pi via I2C. Can I use SMPS for powering both pi and sensors (as a common power source). If yes, how can it be done?
voltage range of sensors is around 3.3V and current drawn is around 600 micro Amps

Answer (score 2):

All commonly sold wall-warts are switching power supplies these days, so you are not doing anything out of the ordinary. You can power the 3.3V sensors from the 3.3V pin on the GPIO header. Search the documentation for the maximum current you can draw, but a few milliamps are definitely safe.